# non string binary code to plain text 16 bit

Tags: c#

Hallo,

how to convert same binary data to plain text. I think there a 16 Bytes rows.

**Have to be**

```
000006F0  DB 4D D9 94 B7 F0 F9 C9 70 F1 D3 7C E3 EC 65 93    .M......p..|..e.
00000700  18 66 FD 0E C1 B9 78 BE 83 14 B0 E0 76 27 3C 69    .f....x.....v'<i
00000710  5F 18 19 FF 5C AC 15 24 84 CF BC F9 F1 04 56 06    _...\..$......V.
00000720  4A 45 07 6D 8B 9F 96 51 8C E7 FE 98 B7 32 87 F6    JE.m...Q.....2..
00000730  94 0B 3F 09 BB 15 E5 9F D3 B2 4D 40 03 DE 23 B2    ..?.......M@..#.
00000740  84 6C 39 37 15 C6 4D 0E 02 57 0B B2 AC 69 A8 7C    .l97..M..W...i.|
00000750  A4 71 D8 DB CF 52 28 10 6C 3C 3E A2 59 B0 CD CF    .q...R(.l<>.Y...
00000760  34 6B D9 9D 7E 5A D3 49 32 E5 91 97 2C AC 40 F2    4k..~Z.I2...,.@.
00000770  8C 15 25 92 07 DE A7 B2 72 22 84 6B CD 33 56 D5    ..%.....r".k.3V.
00000780  72 16 78 5F AD DB FC 12 AE 7D BB 80 AA AE DE 8A    r.x_.....}......
```

**Is right now**

I tried Encoding.ASCII.GetString. My Text length is not always the same like above and there a some special character in my version why ?

```
0200    43 93 87 31 D1 13 50 C2 73 9A 74 12 72 65 1C 23     C??1?P?s?tre#
0220    1D D3 35 6D A9 24 2C EC 70 CC 73 1A 03 14 4D D1     ?5m?$,?p?sM?
0240    13 42 69 2A 2C 45 07 DF A2 D4 72 CB 17 CB 4E A9     Bi*,E???r??N?
0260    F1 1B 53 58 53 1B BF 6C 80 39 B4 66 DB 27 C9 6C     ?SXS?l?9?f?'?l
0280    F3 18 BF 44 A0 2C 4F 84 BA 65 E8 A7 EB 32 B0 30     ??D?,O??e???2?0
02a0    B9 19 39 13 70 B8 A2 10 18 FD 26 4D 23 9B 44 7C     ?9p???&M#?D|
02c0    90 8F F9 B4 16 D6 63 C2 22 0D 7A FD 3E 6A C1 55     ?????c?"z?>j?U
02e0    E8 BA A6 B2 55 D1 2E 95 D1 83 22 C0 CB 64 00 AA     ????U?.???"??d?
0300    E3 21 49 A0 E2 B2 DC 0E 36 C2 04 4B 97 C7 58 35     ?!I????6?K??X5
```

A other thing is the Textbox in WPF. There are no returns (\n) in my text. But the WPF Textbox shows me the text like this :

```
02c0    90 8F F9 B4 16 D6 63 C2 22 0D 7A FD 3E 6A C1 55     ?????c?"z?>j?U
02e0    E8 BA A6 B2 55 D1 2E 95 D1 83 22 C0 CB 64 00 AA     ????U?.
???"??d?
0300    E3 21 49 A0 E2 B2 DC 0E 36 C2 04 4B 97 C7 58 35     ?!I????6?K??X5
```

Comment: it is not clear what you want to achieve... how should the binary be represented as text ? Hex-code ? please show some code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASCII only covers a subset of the possible values you can contain in a byte, so anything outside of the ASCII range will appear as any variety of junk, depending on the default character set of your machine.

You simply need to replace the byte values below 0x20 and above 0x7F with some visible character. (The period in what you want)

```
public static class ByteArrayExt {
    public static byte[] ToASCIIFriendlyArray(this byte[] data) {
        byte[] result = new byte[data.Length];
        for (int i=0;i<data.Length;i++)
            result[i] = b >= 0x20 || b < 0x79 ? b : '.';
        return result;
    }
}
```

---

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data.ToASCIIFriendlyArray());
```

Comment: You might want to reduce the range by one, as ASCII 0x7f isn't printable either.